# Prob. 7, Sec. 4.3, in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis Book: Existence of a particular kind of a bounded linear functional on a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces

Here is Prob. 7, Sec. 4.3, in the book *Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications* by Erwine Kreyszig:

> Give another proof of Theorem 4.3-3 in the case of a Hilbert space.

And, here is Theorem 4.3-3 in Kreyszig:

> Let $X$ be a normed space and let $x_0 \neq 0$ be any element of $X$. Then there exists a bounded linear functional $\tilde{f}$ on $X$ such that
> $$
> \left\lVert \tilde{f} \right\rVert = 1, \qquad \tilde{f} \left( x_0 \right) = \left\lVert x_0 \right\rVert.
> $$

My Attempt:

> Let $x_0$ be a non-zero point of the Hilbert space $X$, and let $$ e_0 := \frac{1}{\left\lVert x_0 \right\rVert} x_0. $$
> Then we have
> $$
> \left\lVert e_0 \right\rVert = 1.
> $$

> Now the functional $\tilde{f}$ on $X$ defined by
> $$
> \tilde{f} (x) := \left\langle x, e_0 \right\rangle \qquad \mbox{for all } x \in X
> $$
> is linear and bounded and has norm
> $$
> \left\lVert \tilde{f} \right\rVert = \left\lVert e_0 \right\rVert = 1.
> $$
> Moreover,
> $$
> \begin{align} 
> \tilde{f} \left( x_0 \right) &= \left\langle x_0, e_0 \right\rangle \\
> &= \left\langle x_0, \frac{1}{ \left\lVert x_0 \right\rVert } x_0 \right\rangle \\
> &= \frac{1}{\left\lVert x_0 \right\rVert } \left\langle x_0, x_0 \right\rangle \\
> &= \frac{1}{\left\lVert x_0 \right\rVert } \left\lVert x_0 \right\rVert^2 \\
> &= \left\lVert x_0 \right\rVert,
> \end{align}
> $$
> as required.

Is this proof satisfactory enough? Or, is it lacking in some respect?

Comment: Looks great, and I feel confident that this is precisely what Kreyszig had in mind for this problem.